# Deletion of data is done reverse order

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
      <head>  
           <title></title>  
           <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
      </head>  
      <body>  
           <br /><br />  
           <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
               
                <br />  
                <div class="table-responsive">  
                     <div align="right">  
                          
                     </div>  
                     <br />  
                     <div id="employee_table">  
                          <table class="table table-bordered">  
                               <tr>  
                                    <th width="70%"> Name</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">Edit</th>  
                                    <th width="15%">View</th>  
         <th width="15%">Delete</th>  
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
                                             
                               {  
          $id=$row['id'];
                               ?>  
                               <tr>  
                                    <td><?php echo $row["employee_name"]; ?></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="edit" value="Edit" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs edit_data" /></td>  
                                    <td><input type="button" name="view" value="view" id="<?php echo $id; ?>" class="btn btn-info btn-xs view_data" /></td>  
         <td><a href="#delete_data_Modal<?php echo $id;?>"><button type="button" name="add" id="deleteBtn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete_data_Modal" class="btn btn-info btn-xs ">delete</button></a></td>  
         
                               </tr>  
                               <?php  
                               }  
                               ?>  
                          </table>  
                     </div>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </body>  
 </html>  
 <div id="dataModal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title">Employee Details</h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body" id="employee_detail">  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>        
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>  
 <div id="add_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" id="insert_form">  
                          <label>Enter Employee Name</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <label>Enter Employee Address</label>  
                          <textarea name="address" id="address" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                          <br />  
                          
                          <label>Enter Age</label>  
                          <input type="text" name="age" id="age" class="form-control" />  
                          <br />  
                          <input type="hidden" name="employee_id" id="employee_id" />  
                          <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" value="Insert" class="btn btn-success" />  
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
                     <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div> 
<div id="delete_data_Modal" class="modal fade">  
      <div class="modal-dialog">  
           <div class="modal-content">  
                <div class="modal-header">  
                     <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>  
                     <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-body">  
                     <form method="post" >  
    
                         <p>Are You Sure Want to Delete this data?????</p>
                     </form>  
                </div>  
                <div class="modal-footer">  
    <a href="delete.php<?php echo '?id='.$id; ?>" class="btn">Delete</a>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">No</button>  
                </div>  
           </div>  
      </div>  
 </div>   

<!---delete.php--->
<?php
require_once('db.php');
 
$get_id=$_GET['id'];

// sql to delete a record
$sql = mysqli_query($conn,"Delete from employee where id = '$get_id' ");

// use exec() because no results are returned
if($sql)
{  
header('location:index.php');
}
else
{
 echo "not";
}
?>
```

This code is to edit, view and display the datas from the table using ajax through bootstrap modal box and which will display the error message after submiting the corresponding buttons. Now editing, updating and viewing datas are going successfully and also displaying error nessage successfully. But, during the time of deletion of data, when click on first delete button last datas are being deleting. Table structure and code for deletion are given above.

Comment: You should take a look at the source code, the delete modal is already there before you click anything and it has a fixed id, the last of your loop. And sql injection.

Comment: can you resend me the corrected code

Comment: That is funny, but no.

Comment: ***reverse order*** Do you wanted to display items in Descending Order ? I.e Last Inserted record will be first record ?